# JSP/JS formatting in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, formatting

Folks is there any plugin for eclipse which provides the standard formatting/indentation.I could find basic settings
at I could find a few basic setting in Web->JSP Files->Editor but does not help much. I am looking for very basic indentation/formatting . Also it can format javascript code in jsp. For example:-

```
<s:if test="myManager">
<s:set var="cust" value="%{'customer'}" />
       <s:set var="custMode" value="%{'custEdit'}" />
            </s:if>
```

**should be changed to below on save**

```
<s:if test="myManager">
  <s:set var="cust" value="%{'customer'}" />
  <s:set var="custMode" value="%{'custEdit'}" />
</s:if>
```

**Javascript Example**

```
function test(){
var test1;
  var test2;
 if(someCondition)
{
  var test3;
}
}
```

**should be changed to below on save**

```
function test(){
  var test1;
  var test2;
  if(someCondition)
    {
       var test3;
    }

}
```

**I am not exaclty looking for above format but yes some meaningful/readable format/indentaion for jsp and javascript code.** I am using eclipse helios. I did not get any open source plugin on net. i am sure there must be some utility available but somehow i am not getting through it .
It would be good if it can format scriplets also.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl + Shift + F`, because it works for me out-of-the-box!

Comment: It does not format javascript code and scriplets